# Map microsoft graph timezone to moment

Tags: timezone, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to map timezone returned by microsoft graph to something more understandable by moment js. There were few instances of timezone like Melbourne timezone is 'AUS Eastern Standard Time' and Brisbane timezone is 'E. AUS Standard Time'. This looks to be confusing and I was wondering if there is any set of predefined timezones I can look into to map those timezones to what I want.

What I've tried is looking to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones. Neither of them have 'E. AUS Standard Time' mentioned. I'm not sure if there are more timezones that are not in this list.

Comment: Can you get data from MS graph in UTC and do the conversion as per the respective timezone using moment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`dateTimeTimeZone` resource type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/datetimetimezone?view=graph-rest-1.0) supports `timeZone` property to be provided in [Windows time zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones) format while Moment supports IANA format, [Unicode CLDR project](https://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml) could be utilized as a reliable data source to map between the two.
For example, according to:

```
<mapZone other="AUS Eastern Standard Time" territory="001" type="Australia/Sydney"/>
```

the request:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events
Prefer:outlook.timezone="AUS Eastern Standard Time"
```

will return events  in  `AUS Eastern Standard Time` Windows timezone which correspond to `Australia/Sydney` IANA time zone identifier

---

Another option would be to *omit* [`Prefer: outlook.timezone` header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) from request, in that case values of `dateTimeTimeZone` values are getting returned in UTC.

Comment: thanks, this is perfect. I'm getting all data in UTC currently but I have a use case where I need to interpret user availability in terms of their local timezone (not the browser timezone).